# VB.NET Save Button stops working after i use delete button

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

ok so i have some sql transactions running in my save to deduct some amounts from stock, also i have some sql transactions in my delete button to add back the stock but when i use the delete button my save button doesnt work anymore

SAVE BUTTON

```
    If cmbProduct.Text = "100LB Saltbread" And chkBajanFlour.Checked = True And chkBrownSugar.Checked = True Then
                ' Open the db connection
                Dim Con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Stock Manager.accdb")
                Con.Open()

                ' Start Transaction
                Dim Trans = Con.BeginTransaction

                'define a comand for the sql statement
                Dim CMD As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Amount FROM [Recipes] WHERE RecipeID=1", Con, Trans)
                Dim i = CMD.ExecuteScalar()
                Dim CMD2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount-@TT) where ItemID=10", Con, Trans)
                CMD2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", i * txtAmount.Text)


                Dim CMD3 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Amount FROM [Recipes] WHERE RecipeID=2", Con, Trans)
                Dim q = CMD3.ExecuteScalar()
                Dim CMD4 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount-@TT) where ItemID=22", Con, Trans)
                CMD4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", q * txtAmount.Text)

                Dim CMD5 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=3", Con, Trans)
                Dim w = CMD5.ExecuteScalar()
                Dim CMD6 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount-@TT) where ItemID=21", Con, Trans)
                CMD6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", w * txtAmount.Text)

                Dim CMD7 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=4", Con, Trans)
                Dim r = CMD7.ExecuteScalar()
                Dim CMD8 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount-@TT) where ItemID=85", Con, Trans)
                CMD8.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", r * txtAmount.Text)

                Dim CMD9 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=5", Con, Trans)
                Dim d = CMD9.ExecuteScalar()
                Dim CMD10 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount-@TT) where ItemID=8", Con, Trans)
                CMD10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", d * txtAmount.Text)

                Dim CMD11 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=6", Con, Trans)
                Dim g = CMD11.ExecuteScalar()
                Dim CMD12 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount-@TT) where ItemID=107", Con, Trans)
                CMD12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", g * txtAmount.Text)

                Dim CMD13 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=7", Con, Trans)
                Dim v = CMD13.ExecuteScalar()
                Dim CMD14 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount-@TT) where ItemID=1", Con, Trans)
                CMD14.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", v * txtAmount.Text)

                Dim CMD15 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=8", Con, Trans)
                Dim a = CMD15.ExecuteScalar()
                Dim CMD16 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount-@TT) where ItemID=2", Con, Trans)
                CMD16.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", a * txtAmount.Text)

                Dim CMD17 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=9", Con, Trans)
                Dim b = CMD17.ExecuteScalar()
                Dim CMD18 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount-@TT) where ItemID=104", Con, Trans)
                CMD18.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", b * txtAmount.Text)

                ' execute the command
                CMD2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                CMD4.ExecuteNonQuery()
                CMD6.ExecuteNonQuery()
                CMD8.ExecuteNonQuery()
                CMD10.ExecuteNonQuery()
                CMD12.ExecuteNonQuery()
                CMD14.ExecuteNonQuery()
                CMD16.ExecuteNonQuery()
                CMD18.ExecuteNonQuery()

                ' save the changes
                Trans.Commit()

                'Close connection
                Con.Close()

            End If
 On Error GoTo SaveErr
        InterimStorageOrdersBindingSource1.EndEdit()
        Interim_Storage_OrdersTableAdapter.Update(Stock_ManagerDataSet.Interim_Storage_Orders)
        MessageBox.Show("Entry Saved")
SaveErr:
        Exit Sub
```

DELETE BUTTON

```
If cmbProduct.Text = "100LB Saltbread" Then
            ' Open the db connection
            Dim Con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Stock Manager.accdb")
            Con.Open()

            ' Start Transaction
            Dim Trans = Con.BeginTransaction

            'define a comand for the sql statement
            Dim CMD As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Amount FROM [Recipes] WHERE RecipeID=1", Con, Trans)
            Dim i = CMD.ExecuteScalar()
            Dim CMD2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount+@TT) where ItemID=10", Con, Trans)
            CMD2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", i * txtAmount.Text)


            Dim CMD3 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Amount FROM [Recipes] WHERE RecipeID=2", Con, Trans)
            Dim q = CMD3.ExecuteScalar()
            Dim CMD4 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount+@TT) where ItemID=22", Con, Trans)
            CMD4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", q * txtAmount.Text)

            Dim CMD5 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=3", Con, Trans)
            Dim w = CMD5.ExecuteScalar()
            Dim CMD6 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount+@TT) where ItemID=21", Con, Trans)
            CMD6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", w * txtAmount.Text)

            Dim CMD7 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=4", Con, Trans)
            Dim r = CMD7.ExecuteScalar()
            Dim CMD8 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount+@TT) where ItemID=85", Con, Trans)
            CMD8.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", r * txtAmount.Text)

            Dim CMD9 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=5", Con, Trans)
            Dim d = CMD9.ExecuteScalar()
            Dim CMD10 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount+@TT) where ItemID=8", Con, Trans)
            CMD10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", d * txtAmount.Text)

            Dim CMD11 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=6", Con, Trans)
            Dim g = CMD11.ExecuteScalar()
            Dim CMD12 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount+@TT) where ItemID=107", Con, Trans)
            CMD12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", g * txtAmount.Text)

            Dim CMD13 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=7", Con, Trans)
            Dim v = CMD13.ExecuteScalar()
            Dim CMD14 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount+@TT) where ItemID=1", Con, Trans)
            CMD14.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", v * txtAmount.Text)

            Dim CMD15 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=8", Con, Trans)
            Dim a = CMD15.ExecuteScalar()
            Dim CMD16 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount+@TT) where ItemID=2", Con, Trans)
            CMD16.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", a * txtAmount.Text)

            Dim CMD17 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Amount from [Recipes] where RecipeID=9", Con, Trans)
            Dim b = CMD17.ExecuteScalar()
            Dim CMD18 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update [Stock] set Amount=(Amount+@TT) where ItemID=104", Con, Trans)
            CMD18.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", b * txtAmount.Text)

            ' execute the command
            CMD2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CMD4.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CMD6.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CMD8.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CMD10.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CMD12.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CMD14.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CMD16.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CMD18.ExecuteNonQuery()

            ' save the changes
            Trans.Commit()

            'Close connection
            Con.Close()

        End If
    InterimStorageOrdersBindingSource1.RemoveCurrent
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work anymore".  What *does* it do?  When you step through in a debugger, where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: every time i add a new entry and hit save nothing saves to the databse and the msgbox doesn't pop up @David

Comment: Right, but have you stepped through the code in a debugger?  The code isn't a black box, you can actually examine it.  Don't just observe the end result and give up, step through the code in a debugger and see what it's doing.

Comment: Time to ditch those On Error GoTo statements.  Maybe you should turn "Option Strict On" in your code to see the many potential problems your code has with assuming strings are numbers.  Put a Debug - Toggle Breakpoint at the beginning of the function and step through the code line by line.  Make sure your buttons have the click event handler configured.

Comment: i am getting ''Concurrency violation: the DeleteCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.''

Answer (score 0):

Me.Stock_ManagerDataSet.Interim_Storage_Orders.AcceptChanges()

i added that line of code to my save button and it fixed the problem :D